# Fn lock/unlock HP Spectre x360

Tags: laptop, keyboard, fn-key, hp-spectre

I have used HP Spectre x360 for 1 year.

<kbd>Fn</kbd> key used for small icon function in <kbd>F1</kbd>~<kbd>F12</kbd> keys is suddenly locked, I don't know what happened.

I want to use <kbd>F1</kbd>~<kbd>F12</kbd> keys for original function to use excel shortcut.

I have tried all keys in the post below (e.g. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Caps</kbd>, etc.) but failed.

[HP laptop F1-12 keys inverted with Fn](https://superuser.com/questions/279809/hp-laptop-f1-12-keys-inverted-with-fn?newreg=d58589e06ef047d9a443108ebb9e8d55)

Do I have to enter a BIOS to disable <kbd>Fn</kbd> lock seriously?
Please help me.

Comment: On some HP's you do have to change it in the bios.

Comment: Oh...Thanks for the answer Moab.